# Angular Universal: serving critical CSS and delaying non-critical

Tags: css, angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-universal, lighthouse

This is basically [the code I am using](https://github.com/evertonrobertoauler/universal-demo-v5) and lighthouse says my (almost empty!) css bundle is delaying my initial load.

So how do I put a link to critical.scss in the

`<head><style>DONT_WANT_TO_WRITE_STUFF_INLINED</style>...</head>`

Is there a better solution than https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical or writing everything inlined?

And how do I delay the load of the main styles.scss until the prerendered Universal content is loaded in the browser? The server-app's config in angular-cli.json does not contain `styles` or `assets`, so I don't understand why styles.scss is loaded initially

Comment: man did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry no, I didn't. I stopped worrying about load time differences of 10ms. Having maintainable code is more important. If you want to focus 100% on SEO I suggest you rather use AMP instead of Angular in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding delaying the load of the main styles.scss, I rely on two things:

- First of all, I build the application with the `--extract-css=false` flag. That ensures that the styles bundle will be a JavaScript file.
- Second, I defer the loading of that file. To do so I rely on a small script that I called `defer.styles.js` and that runs at the end of the build process. That script simply looks for the script tag that loads the styles, and adds a `defer` to it.

```
const path = require('path');

const htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'browser', 'index.html');

fs.readFile(htmlPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    const index = data.search(`src="styles.`);

    if (index > -1) {
        const output = [data.slice(0, index), 'defer ', data.slice(index)].join('');
        console.log(output);
        fs.writeFile(htmlPath, output, 'utf8', () => {
            console.log('Styles succesfully deferred');
        })
    }
});
```

Regarding your other question - how to load the critical css -. I still didn't find a way of comfortably doing it.